# How to define forms to persist complex objects in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, persist

I need to define a from to create instances of one of my objects. This is an easy task and I already have some, but this specific object has a reference to other object that I must define in the form. How can this be done? I know I could ask the user to enter de id, store it in a DTO and get the real object later but I suppose that this is not the best way to accomplish this. What can I do?

I put here my entities:

```
@Entity
public class Route {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long distance;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Place origin;

}
```

And this is the references object:

```
@Entity
public class Place {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private Long latitude;

    private Long longitude;

    private String imagePath;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "origin", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Route> originRoutes;

}
```

Comment: Are they the only 2 entities backing the form?

Comment: If you have smalller amount of Places (which I suppose is not the case) you could put List of all places as model attribute and display them in  a select box, which would bind to a place ID in the backing form object. If you have large amount of Places I guess the best approach would be to create some AJAX autocompletion of the Place based on its name for Example.

Comment: @JamieWhite yeah, I only use those entities in that form.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt Could you show me a sample? What would I retrieve? the whole object? And how would I save it?

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía You mean sample of the first or the second (autocomplete) solution?

Comment: You don't need a dto object. You can access route object via path="place.route_field"...

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt Oops, sorry. The second one. I have too many places. I can't use a list.

Comment: @JamieWhite But I'm talking about create a Route. How can I map a form controller with a place?

Comment: @JamieWhite But I don't want an empty Route. I wan't to set the route.

Comment: @AlanHay Nope. That is only a list and I have a huge collection of places. I can't add a list.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on what is the use case in more details. Let's think of couple of possibilities:

**Create a *Place* together with some *Routes* instantly at one go** - in this case I would implement the view so that it creates a complex structure reflecting the entities one to one like you have them defined for JPA, and passes in single POST request. We basically assume that there is limited number of routes that are always created together with places. *Routes* cannot be shared among different *Places* as it makes no sense.

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/places")
public CreatePlaceResponse createPlace(@RequestBody Place place) {
  ...
}
```

**Create a *Place* and provide *Routes* in subsequent requests.** - if we want more flexibility and/or expect the number of routes assigned to each place to be large, we may first create a *Place* and after that use another request to assign *Routes* to it (by referring to a place id). This way you let the user create the whole structure step by step, plus you give a possibility to add a *Route* later on.

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/places")
public CreatePlaceResponse createPlace(@RequestBody Place place) {
  ...
}

@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/places/{placeId}")
public AddRouteResponse addRoute(@RequestBody Route route) {
  ...
}
```

Depending on case you can also think of bulk creation of *Routes* as well, so passing a list of *Routes* to an already created place.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to ad places to routes. Actually that relationship could be uniderectional. I only need to create routes in which I need to set the origin place and the destination place. I removed the destination variables to make the sample easier to read.

Comment: Well, that's exactly as I understood that. First create a place and then assign routes to it. I can't see destination property in your Route entity. If that is the case your definitely need to make it two steps. So first define places, and then bind it with a route in separate call. The requests would look a bit different in that case.

Answer (score 0):

On the UI side I can see this working using either a hidden field to store the place id in response to the text entered or a 'fancy' select such as one of these at the below which let you type into the select to filter and won't load 1000s of record in memory at once:

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Either way, you are going to bind the hidden field or the selected option to:

route.place

e.g.

```
<form:hidden path="place" value="id_of_place_updated_by_javascript" />
```

or

```
<form:select path="place">
```

You will then register a converter which will convert the submitted value to the required type i.e. Place. On submit your converter takes the Place ID and retrieves the corresponding Place from the Database. The framework will then bind the Place returned by the Converter to the Route backing the form.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert

See here for an example using a Formatter to do the conversion:

http://springinpractice.com/2012/01/07/making-formselect-work-nicely-using-spring-3-formatters

In the final example you would just go off to the database to get the relevant entity rather than creating a new instance.